# how to remove desktop background in windows 7

Tags: windows-7

how to remove desktop background  picture in windows 7?

Comment: Do you mean the background picture? To you want to have a single color only?

Comment: yeah that's right. I want a white one

Answer (score 10, accepted):

go to desktop , right click and go to Personalization .

then, Desktop Background > choose Solid color .. you will see what you want.

[image]